# Dynamic equations creation for optimize SciPy fsolve function

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am using scipy optimize function to solve some non-linear equations. However I have 11 equations whose variable can change, So I need to create non-linear equations for the opt.fsolve function.

I tried to write a formulation where I created equations using a function and stored them in a list. The list has 11 equations in the form of
a*b = 2.6, a * k = 4.6, b * g = 3.6, j * b = 1.6  etc. I have 11 equations like this in total.

```
def f(variables) :
 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) = variables
 eq_1=eq_list[0]
 eq_2=eq_list[1] 
 eq_3=eq_list[2] 
 eq_4=eq_list[3] 
 eq_5=eq_list[4] 
 eq_6=eq_list[5] 
 eq_7=eq_list[6] 
 eq_8=eq_list[7] 
 eq_9=eq_list[8]
 eq_10=eq_list[9] 
 eq_11=eq_list[10]
return [eq_1,eq_2 ,eq_3,eq_4 ,eq_5,eq_6,eq_7,eq_8,eq_9,eq_10,eq_11]

solution = opt.fsolve(f, (0.1, 1,1,0.1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,)) # fsolve(equations, X_0)
```

But as these equations are in string format the function throws an exception.
Exception "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."

I am trying to use the following sample

```
def f(variables) :
 (x,y) = variables
 first_eq = x + y**2 - 4
 print(type(x))
 second_eq = exp(x) + x*y - 3
 return [first_eq, second_eq]
solution = opt.fsolve(f, (0.1, 1)) # fsolve(equations, X_0)  
print(solution)
```

Is there a way around to achieve what I am trying to do?
I need to use the above function after creating my equations dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `scipy.optimize.fsolve` expects each equation to equal `0`, so you need to transform the equations by doing a pass that moves the things on the right of the equals sign to the left. Then you can unpack the variables and iterate through each expression and simply use `eval` to evaluate them. So you can do something like this:

```py
import scipy.optimize as opt
from math import exp 

eq_list = ["x + y**2 = 4", "exp(x) + x*y = 3"]
eq_list_altered = []
for eq in eq_list:
    start, end = eq.split('=')
    eq_list_altered.append(start + '-' + end)

def f(variables) :
    (x,y) = variables
    res = []
    for eq in eq_list_altered:
        res.append(eval(eq))
    return res

solution = opt.fsolve(f, (0.1, 1))
print(solution)
```

Note that it normally isn't recommended to use `eval` because it can run arbitrary code, so make sure that the strings are only expressions from trusted sources. More on security issues of eval can be found [here](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#minimizing-the-security-issues-of-eval).